# What does it mean the following C statement? ((int*) & var)

Tags: python, c, casting, crc16

I have the following code in C to calculate a CRC16-USB for some data flows:

```
uint16_t DRV_CANFDSPI_CalculateCRC16(uint8_t* data, uint16_t size)
{
    uint16_t init = CRCBASE;
    uint8_t index;

    while (size-- != 0) {
        index = ((uint8_t*) & init)[1] ^ *data++;
        init = (init << 8) ^ crc16_table[index];
    }

    return init;
}
```

Where *crc16_table* is an array of some hex values of 2 bytes (like 0xAFF3) , and *data* is an array of hex values of 1 byte (like 0xA3) representing the data stream (aqcuired by other means). *Size* is the length of the *data* array.

I want to reproduce this piece of code in Python, but I don't know that this statement means:

```
index = ((uint8_t*) & init)[1] ^ *data++;
```

I would like to understand that does this statament means and does, so I can reproduce it in Python. I am not an expert in C but have some knowledge, and I mostly undestand the rest of the code, but this line is giving me a headache.

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: It casts the address of a `uint16_t` variable to be a pointer to `uint8_t`.

Comment: It is taking second byte of `init`  and XORing it with value pointed to by `data`, increasing `data` after this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`init` has type `uint16_t`, so the *expression* `&init` has type "pointer to `uint16_t`", or `uint16_t *`.  The expression `(uint8_t *) &init` means "get the address of `init`, but treat that as the address of a `uint8_t` object, rather than a `uint16_t` object".

That address is then used with a subscript operator - `((uint8_t *) &init)[1]`, which is basically equivalent to "treat `init` as an array of two `uint8_t` objects, and give me the value of the second element in that array".

Graphically:

```
      +---+
init: |   | <-- ((uint8_t *) &init)[0]
      +---+
      |   | <-- ((uint8_t *) &init)[1]
      +---+
```

So, basically, you're grabbing the lower 8 bits of `init`, bitwise XORing that with the value of the current byte of the input message, and then advancing `data` to point to the next byte of the input message.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my problem, with the following code:

```
def calculateCRC16(data):
    init = 0xFFFF
    for byte in data:
        index = (init >> 8) ^ byte
        init = ((init << 8) ^ crc16_table[index]) & 0xFFFF
    return init
```

I think it is fairly simple. I tested this code with the above one in C and the results are the same. The masking in Python in the variable *init* is necessary as Python does not limit int variables to a fixed bit size. Also, in C,  lib should be included for the code to work.

Answer (score -1):

The intent of the `index = ((uint8_t*) & init)[1] ^ *data++;` statement is to XOR the high eight bits of `init` with the next byte of `data` (and to increment `data). Unfortunately, it is written improperly.

In the statement `index = ((uint8_t*) & init)[1] ^ *data++;`:

- `& init` takes the address of `init` (which was defined with `uint16_t init = CRCBASE;`).
- `(uint8_t*)` converts that address to a pointer to `uint8_t`. Further use of this pointer requires that `uint8_t` be a character type in the C implementation, which is likely but is not guaranteed by the C standard.
- Applying `[1]` to this pointer fetches the next byte beyond where the pointer points. The fact that the second line uses `init << 8`, which results in a value solely dependent on the *low** eight bits of `init`, suggests that the intent in this first line was to fetch the **high** eight bits of `init`.

However, the C standard does not require that the bytes of a `uint16_t` be in any particular order, so it is not assured that using `[1]` will fetch the desired bits. And it is unnecessary; using `init >> 8` in place of `((uint8_t*) & init)[1]` would provide the desired bits.

Thus, the code could have been simply:

```
while (size--)
    init = init << 8 ^ crc16_table[init>>8 ^ *data++];
```